Can hydrogen aquire magnetic moment?
Is the orientation of the electron inside its orbit around the proton inside the hydrogen atom dependent of the proton spin orientation... (as the spins of the two particles are cancelled out.)So if we neglect the spin of the electron is the magnetic moment of the orbiting electron in direction or not regarding the spin magnetic moment of the proton? Thanks for answering this question...

This is on a different but related topic. You may find bits of it helpful - MAGNETS: How Do They Work?

You seem to think the electron orbits the proton like the moon orbits the Earth. It doesn’t.
